# How to show bootstrap nav-tabs as a collapsible button on the small screens?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm building single page app that should be responsive on all devices. So far everything works fine but there is one thing that caught my eye. The tabs on the home screen show horizontally when `lg` and `md` screen size. If I turn on `Responsive Design Mode` in the browser they show vertically. That presentation takes a lot of space on the screen. I'm wondering if they can be displayed as a collapsible button where user can click and choose the tab? That would save some space on the screen and definitely look nicer. Here is example of what I have so far:

```css
.navbar-brand {
    padding: 0px;
}
.navbar-brand>img {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 45px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: auto;
}
.brand2 {
    height: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    width: auto;
    display: block;
}
.my-jumbotron {
    padding-top: 45px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff; 
}
.page-footer {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    background-color: #333; 
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 5px;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Single Page Application</title>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/favicon.ico" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <nav id="myNavbar" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-6">
            <a class="navbar-brand" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="MyApp home page" href="https://www.example.com" target="_blank"><img class="img-rounded" src="images/logo.png" alt="MyApp" /></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-6">
            <img class="img-rounded brand2" src="images/app.jpg" alt="Img" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="nav_menu">
          <li><a href="#" data-id="home">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" data-id="contact">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" data-id="help">Help</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron my-jumbotron">
      <h2>Single Page Application</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="main_container">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab3">Tab 3</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab4">Tab 4</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="tab-content">
        
        <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane my-tab-pane fade in active">
          <h3>Tab 1</h3>
          <p>Show tab 1.</p>
        </div>
        
        <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane my-tab-pane fade">
          <h3>Tab 2</h3>
          <p>Show tab 2.</p>
        </div>
        
        <div id="tab3" class="tab-pane my-tab-pane fade">
          <h3>Tab 3</h3>
          <p>Show tab 3.</p>
        </div>
        
        <div id="tab4" class="tab-pane my-tab-pane fade">
          <h3>Tab 4</h3>
          <p>Show tab 4.</p>
        </div>  
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <footer class="page-footer">
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                  <a href="http://example1.com" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="example1.com">Example1.com</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                  <a href="http://example2.com/" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="example2.com">Example2.com</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                  <a href="http://example3.com/" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="example3.com">Example3.com</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                  <a href="http://example4.com/" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="example4.com">Example4.com</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </footer>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

If you check the example above you will see tabs on top of each other. If you take a look in the upper right corner you will see button that you can click on. Then you will get list of items in the menu `Home`, `Contact` or `Help`. I would like to have something similar for the tabs on the small screen. If someone knows a good way to achieve that please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will be helpful. I made a fiddle just of your nav tabs

https://jsfiddle.net/nk7wp0m8/4/

```
@media only screen and (max-width:800px) {
  .nav-tabs.nav-justified>li {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
  }
}
```

If you were to determine the width that your page has them start stacking on then you could use the above media query and force them to all display beside one another.

**EDIT**

https://jsfiddle.net/7cL126q9/

This fiddle gives you a display like your navigation with the home, contact etc.

Comment: I checked you example and seems that you organized them horizontally. I was wondering if they can be collapsible button instead of horizontal display on the small screens?

Comment: So you mean almost like the bootstrap collapse type of display. You may want to just use that in the first place and save yourself the work of trying to re-engineer this all yourself - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/

Comment: Did you check button in the header of my example? If you click on that button you will see Home, Contact and Help options. The same way I want to show tabs on the small screen.

Comment: Check the edit above for something that's more in line with what you're looking for